# WPF Threading and Dispather.Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I get this error at line (*):

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll Additional information: This API was accessed
>   with arguments from the wrong context.*

The curious thing is that it passes the line above this.
My City element is loaded in MainWindow.xaml like an Image for examle.

Does anyone have ideas?

```
public class City : FrameworkElement
{
    VisualCollection _buildingsList;

    public City()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Draw));
        t.start();
    }

    private void Draw() 
    {
        DrawingVisual building = new DrawingVisual();

        // [...]

        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            _buildingsList.Clear();
            _buildingsList.Add(building); // (*)
        }));
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return _buildingsList[index];
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return _buildingsList.Count; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All UI objects should be added and created on UI thread only.**

In your case you are *creating DrawingVisual on background thread and adding it in VisualCollection on UI thread*. You should create DrawingVisual also on UI thread.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
{
   DrawingVisual building = new DrawingVisual(); <-- Create on UI thread.
   _buildingsList.Clear();
   _buildingsList.Add(building);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are another thread what the program wants.

Please check the following [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456928/wpf-take-screenshot-from-other-thread-than-main-thread), ad test your code.