# Add a child on UI thread -> n unhandled exception of type "System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException" occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Visual Studio 2013 & Visual Basic.NET, WPF

I have implemented the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423204/wpf-threading-and-dispather-invoke), and it works! But there is a problem:

The *second* time through, the app crashes with:

**An unhandled exception of type "System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException" occurred in mscorlib.dll**

picture might be here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYh1z.jpg )

My code (one class):

```
Private Delegate Sub AddAChildDelegate()

AddHandler Q.PeekCompleted, AddressOf GetChild
Sub GetChild()
        AddAChild()
End Sub

Private Sub AddAChild()
If Not Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess Then
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(New AddAChildDelegate(AddressOf AddAChild))
        Exit Sub
    Else
        [code to add a child on UI thread (#1)]
    End If
End Sub
```

The FIRST time through AddAChild, **System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId** is an arbitrary # > 1. But when the dispatcher invokes it again via delegate, **System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId** is 1 (the UI thread, I'm guessing).

Is it possible that the 're-calling' of the sub (via delegate) on the UI thread is somehow clashing with the next call from the Q? I don't even know how to troubleshoot, to be honest. :(

Comment: Why is `AddAChild` a function returning a `Boolean`? May not be the issue but seems pointless, especially how you've implemented it.  What's in the `Else` block?

Comment: I just realised that your `AddAChildDelelgate` is declared as a `Sub`, which makes `AddAChild` being a `Boolean` `Function` even more wrong.

Comment: You are correct. I had tried both, and was in-between approaches. I edited the above to show all Sub, and the error is unchanged. It is very difficult to pinpoint why, but it is at the point the the AddAChild() sub is called on the UI thread(#1?) that the program crashes (goes to Application.g.vb). i turned on "Output" window 'process thread exit messages', but no details given in logs of why it crashes. Any hints on t-shoot to see what  &where counts are expected?

Comment: Your `GetChild` method is supposed to be handling an event but it has no parameters.  Event handlers usually have two parameters.  That might explain the `TargetParameterCountException`.  What is the signature of that `PeekCompleted` event?

Comment: @jmcilhinney thx for writing! I did simplify it:  Sub GetChild(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As PeekCompletedEventArgs) --- at the end of GetChild() there is a call to: Me.Q.BeginPeek(), and in the constructor:   AddHandler Q.PeekCompleted, AddressOf GetChild ...since the GetChild isn't called by the Delegate, I didn't think they were related. Sorry!